# Escaping/Encoding of Header for Java HTTP request

Tags: java, encoding, httprequest, http-get

I am executing a simple Java HttpGet request with an API Key provided in a header field called "authorization".

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://someURL.com");
get.setHeader("authorization", "myAPIKEyhere...");
CloseableHttpResponse = response = httpClient.execute(get);
```

It works perfectly fine if I run the code locally (and in Postman as well), but if I deploy it to my server (Google Cloud) I get an authorization error. Since the API key contains some special character like "." or ":" I was wondering if I need to escape or encode something and played around with `URLEncode` and escaping, but nothing helped.

This is an example API key:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcGlfdG9rZW5faWQzOiJjOGJhNDc0My0wNDgyLTQ2NWEtYmE2NS0wOGYzNTk1YTljNmIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJzY29wZV9leGNoYW5nZV9sZWRnZXJfcmVhZCIsInNjb3BlX2V4Y2hhbmdlX2Z1bmRpbmdfcmVhZCIsInNjb3BlX2V4Y2hhbmdlX2Z1bnRpbmdfd3JpdGUiXSwidXNlcl9pZCI6Ijc5N2ZhY2EyLWQ2YzgtNGQ2Ny1hNzUzLTkyYzI2MjFkM2U1MyJ9.0h6w3nX4w3HO6r2DJl0W75fQ4VM8rItRgBkwQtqee88.V2:b4b82e785b0aaf1dcbd3c89e16b92532db3abc0b5c4115436b1fae31246aba430

Maybe the length of it is an issue? Any suggestings what could solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry, you say URLEncode and escaping didn't work. What specifically did you try?

Comment: Tried it like that: URLEncoder.encode("myAPIKEyhere...", "UTF-8")) or by replacing "." by "\\.". By doing stuff like that it stops working locally as well.